# Can AWS dynamoDB or DocumentDB to call another aws service at a date stored inside them?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, triggers, architecture

Is it possible to have DynamoDB or DocumentDB or any DB in AWS call another AWS service at a date determined by an item stored in that DB?

Let stay I have an item that has a date and I want at that date to run a certain task in AWS, be it lambda, SQS, Step functions e.t.c. Is it possible that the DB can automatically call that service at that given date? So that even when I change the date the DB will just call the service at the new date?

Comment: You can use something like [EventBridge](https://aws.amazon.com/tutorials/scheduling-a-serverless-workflow-step-functions-amazon-eventbridge-scheduler/) to call another endpoint.

Comment: Thanks @AnonCoward. Is there a way for a dB to automatically do that and avoid EventBridge?

Comment: No.  You could create a [trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html), but that's a Lambda that runs in response to data change.  DynamoDB has no concept of running code in response to timed events.